# Storing and retrieving locations in SQLite from Google Maps Android API V2

Tags: android, geolocation, android-sqlite, google-maps-android-api-2

Everytime I've tried to test my app on my phone, It shows a prompt that says "Unfortunately, the app has stopped."

I have already checked the build path, I've made sure that Google play services library is added. I've tried searching several threads already on how to fix and none of them are working. So I've made this post as a last resort to get someone to check it manually.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />    

    <permission
          android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>       

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <provider 
            android:name="LocationsContentProvider"
            android:authorities="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.locations"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main activity.java:

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available           

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);           

            // Invoke LoaderCallbacks to retrieve and draw already saved locations in map
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);            
        }        

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {      


                // Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(point);          

                // Creating an instance of ContentValues
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                // Setting latitude in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, point.latitude );

                // Setting longitude in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, point.longitude);

                // Setting zoom in ContentValues
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM, googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);

                // Creating an instance of LocationInsertTask
                LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();

                // Storing the latitude, longitude and zoom level to SQLite database
                insertTask.execute(contentValues);                

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marker is added to the Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  

            }
        }); 


        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

                // Removing all markers from the Google Map
                googleMap.clear();

                // Creating an instance of LocationDeleteTask
                LocationDeleteTask deleteTask = new LocationDeleteTask();

                // Deleting all the rows from SQLite database table
                deleteTask.execute();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All markers are removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }


    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                  

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);         
    }


    private class LocationInsertTask extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {

            /** Setting up values to insert the clicked location into SQLite database */           
            getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);            
            return null;
        }       
    }

    private class LocationDeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            /** Deleting all the locations stored in SQLite database */
            getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);          
            return null;
        }       
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0,
            Bundle arg1) {

        // Uri to the content provider LocationsContentProvider
        Uri uri = LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;

        // Fetches all the rows from locations table
        return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0,
            Cursor arg1) {
        int locationCount = 0;
        double lat=0;
        double lng=0;
        float zoom=0;

        // Number of locations available in the SQLite database table
        locationCount = arg1.getCount();

        // Move the current record pointer to the first row of the table
        arg1.moveToFirst();

        for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

            // Get the latitude
            lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));

            // Get the longitude
            lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));

            // Get the zoom level
            zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));

            // Creating an instance of LatLng to plot the location in Google Maps
            LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Drawing the marker in the Google Maps
            drawMarker(location);

            // Traverse the pointer to the next row
            arg1.moveToNext();
        }

        if(locationCount>0){
            // Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng)));

            // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));  

        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }   
}
```

LocationDB.java :

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class LocationsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    /** Database name */
    private static String DBNAME = "locationmarkersqlite";

    /** Version number of the database */
    private static int VERSION = 1;

    /** Field 1 of the table locations, which is the primary key */
    public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";

    /** Field 2 of the table locations, stores the latitude */
    public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";

    /** Field 3 of the table locations, stores the longitude*/
    public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";

    /** Field 4 of the table locations, stores the zoom level of map*/
    public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zom";

    /** A constant, stores the the table name */
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";

    /** An instance variable for SQLiteDatabase */
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;  


    /** Constructor */
    public LocationsDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);  
        this.mDB = getWritableDatabase();
    }


    /** This is a callback method, invoked when the method getReadableDatabase() / getWritableDatabase() is called 
      * provided the database does not exists 
    * */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql =    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                            FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                            FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
                            FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
                            FIELD_ZOOM + " text " +
                        " ) ";

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    /** Inserts a new location to the table locations */
    public long insert(ContentValues contentValues){
        long rowID = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        return rowID;

    }   


    /** Deletes all locations from the table */
    public int del(){
        int cnt = mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null , null);      
        return cnt;
    }

    /** Returns all the locations from the table */
    public Cursor getAllLocations(){
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_LAT , FIELD_LNG, FIELD_ZOOM } , null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

LocationContenteProvider.java:

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;

/** A custom Content Provider to do the database operations */
public class LocationsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

    public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.locations";

    /** A uri to do operations on locations table. A content provider is identified by its uri */
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/locations" );

    /** Constant to identify the requested operation */
    private static final int LOCATIONS = 1; 

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "locations", LOCATIONS);       
    }

    /** This content provider does the database operations by this object */
    LocationsDB mLocationsDB;

    /** A callback method which is invoked when the content provider is starting up */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mLocationsDB = new LocationsDB(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    /** A callback method which is invoked when insert operation is requested on this content provider */
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        long rowID = mLocationsDB.insert(values);
        Uri _uri=null;
        if(rowID>0){
            _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
        }else {     
            try {
                throw new SQLException("Failed to insert : " + uri);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return _uri;    
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    /** A callback method which is invoked when delete operation is requested on this content provider */
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int cnt = 0;        
        cnt = mLocationsDB.del();   
        return cnt;
    }

    /** A callback method which is invoked by default content uri */
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) { 

        if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==LOCATIONS){
            return mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {        
        return null;
    }   
}
```

LogCat:

```
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationmarkersqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-06 18:13:23.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2219):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: The `NullPointerException` happens on line 60 in `MainActivity`. Line 60 is `googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {...`. This tells me your class member `googleMap` is null. I would set a break point at line 36 and step through your code to verify `googleMap` gets initialized in your if-else statement.

Comment: I would also suggest adding the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission to your manifest as this is recommended in the [Maps v2 Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) guide. That looks like the only permission missing in your manifest based on what is suggested in the guide.

Answer (score 1):

I also trying the same code one problem that i solved, the error at onMapClickListner()  is in your `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`
In your mapActivity layout file